# Vue - passing a variable as a component prop

Tags: vue.js, variables, timer, properties, countdown

I'm new to vue and I downloaded this Pomodoro timer component for my app (https://github.com/P3trur0/vuemodoro) which works well, except the time isn't adjustable inside the app itself.

Im trying to make an input field where the number of minutes will be entered and passed to the pomodoro timer, using the built in "minutes" property, but I don't understand how or if it's possible to pass variables to component properties in this way.

```html
    '''
    
    <div>
        <b-field class="timer">
            <b-numberinput v-model="number"></b-numberinput>
        </b-field>
        <Pomodoro :minutes="1"/>
    </div>
    
    '''
```

Comment: You would pass `number` instead of `1` to `:minutes`, so you the input is passed to the timer. That is, considering that the timer has a minutes prop which you can access...but your code should work (not throw errors) as it is right now, but with a non-changable 1 minute timer (since you hardcoded 1)--does it not work right now?

Comment: It works with the hardcoded 1, but it's just a placeholder and I want the time to be adjustable within the app with the input field. When I use "number" or "{{number}}" inside the :minutes property it either doesn't work at all or the timer just defaults to 25 minutes and doesn't change at all according to the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it seems that the Pomodoro component does not support reactive properties, so, while the timer will correctly be set to the initial value of `number`, it will not update if `number` changes. But - don't worry - there's an easy way around this: setting a `key` to the timer:

```
<Pomodoro :key="number" :minutes="number" />
```

A key tells Vue to update the component when the key has changed, so, in this case, whenever `number` changes, the Pomodoro element will be updated. More info on keys [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).

Without a **key**:

[image: without key]

With a **key**:

[image: with key]

This is the full code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-field class="timer">
      <b-numberinput v-model="number"></b-numberinput>
    </b-field>
    <Pomodoro :key="number" :minutes="number" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Pomodoro from "vuemodoro";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      number: 0,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Pomodoro,
  },
  // rest of the component
};
</script>
```

Also, you can try out this [demo](https://1jjer.csb.app/), and view/edit the [code behind it](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-bash-1jjer?file=/src/App.vue:0-486)

Comment: Oh, that works great! Thank you so much I understand it now!